# Configuring Laravel project in DirectAdmin server

Tags: laravel, github, virtual-machine, homestead, directadmin

I'm a newbie to Laravel projects but I need to have one accessible over the internet so I tried using DirectAdmin but whenever I go to my domain I get an index (pictures attached).

I renamed the Laravel 'public' folder to 'public_html', is that correct? Here is my file structure. [image: File structure]

Here is what I get when I go to my assigned domain which isn't my website at all. [image: Current webpage]

The webpage should look something like this [image: What the webpage should look like]

I also found a laravel app using Softaculous linked here (https://panel.freehosting.com:2222/CMD_PLUGINS/softaculous/index.raw?act=software&soft=419). Am I required to use this app?

Answer (score 1):

At first, you need to learn about the [**laravel directory structure**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/structure). You don't need to change the laravel **public** folder to **public_html**. I am not sure how the DirectAdmin server works. but if you see a laravel directory instead of serving an application it's might be a path-related issue in your server. your domain should serve your application public folder.

I just found [**a tutorial**](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-laravel-on-a-directadmin-server/) for the DirectAdmin server with laravel. that might help.

Comment: Thank you, I found a Laravel app too that inputs the directory so I appreciate it